# Mobil Version redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I am trying to customize a cargo2 template and don't have access to html head, only body and css. I can, however add meta tags into head. 
I am trying to redirect to a mobile version based on a screen size and this is what I used so far, but it's not working, because I don't have access to html head portion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 700) {
window.location = "http://www.mobile-site.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.innerWidth` or `window.outerWidth`.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth

Comment: Thank you so much nicktu12, can you elaborate a little? Not super familiar how window.innerWidth or window.outerWidth will help. I thought it's more to change a size of a window type of a deal... Thanks in advance